# Update Mail Count With Angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, updating

I am trying to continuously keep an updated count of the unread messages. The angular code I have right now doesn't replace the current count but simply puts the new count next to it. Over and over again. I am really not if I am  using the right method for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chatApp')
.controller('ViewedCtrl', function($scope, Mail, $interval) {

    var countLoaded = function(count) {
         $scope.count = count;
    }

    var handleErrors = function(response) {
        console.error(response);
    }

    var getUpdates = function() {
    return Mail.viewed().then(updatesLoaded);
    }

    var updatesLoaded = function(updates) {
        $scope.count = $scope.count.concat(updates);
    }

    $interval(getUpdates, 3000);

        Mail.count()
        .then(countLoaded)
        .then(getUpdates)
        .catch(handleErrors);

});
```

I have `{{count}}` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! The problem is in your `updatesLoaded` function. You are using the `concat` function which will append your `updates` to your `$scope.count` variable.

For example:

```
// with a string
var someString = 'Hello'
someString = someString.concat(' world!') // 'Hello world!'

// with an array
var someArray = [1, 2]
someArray = someArray.concat([3]) // [1, 2, 3]
```

What you probably want is to just assign `$scope.count` to whatever is the current count of unread mail.

So depending on what the value of `updates` is, something like this could work:

```
var updatesLoaded = function (updates) {
  $scope.count = updates
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, that is what I thought was going on. I not familiar at all with angular so didn't know what to use instead of concat. Thanks for your time hopefully I'll be able  to figure it out.